# Distribution of a method for generating random whole numbers with a given sum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random, integer-partitions

I am writing a computer program which involves generating 5 random non negative integer numbers with a specific sum, namely 30.

I've found this method, but I don't know if it really generates a uniform distribution for all 5-uples.

I generate 4 random numbers $x\leq y\leq z\leq w$ between 0 and 100. Then my 5 random numbers are
$$ 
a=x,\;b=y-x,\;c=z-y,\;d=w-z,\;e=100-w
$$

Is this method correct or it gives a different distribution? For example, is (0,0,0,0,100) likely as much as (0,0,0,100,0)?

Comment: How do you generate your numbers $x,y,z,w$?

Comment: I'm working with C++, so I use $x$= rand()%101, but I don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: @user627482 I think the main challenge here is that rand()%101 [*does not* lead to random uniform integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153589/generating-a-uniform-random-integer-in-c)

Comment: Another, and what worries me more, is that $x\le y\le z\le w$ is not likely to come about from calls  to rand()%101.  So you are in fact doing something other than what you described. Like sorting the numbers, or playing "go fish" until $x\le y\le z\le w$ happens, or something.

Comment: But if $x,y,z,w$ are truly random numbers, does that method work?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, it's not entirely clear what you mean by “I generate $4$ random numbers $x\leq y\leq z\leq w$ between $0$ and $100$”. I’ll assume that what you mean is that you independently uniformly randomly generate $4$ numbers in $[0,100]$ and then sort them into that order.

By and large your approach is good, but you have a slight bias against generating $0$ because the tuples with difference $0$ are less likely to occur than other tuples. For instance, you only have one chance to generate $(0,0,0,0,100)$ (namely with $x=y=z=w=0$) but $4!=24$ chances to generate e.g. $(1,1,1,1,96)$ (namely with all permutations of $x,y,z,w=1,2,3,4$).

The accepted answer to [Method of generating random numbers that sum to 100 - is this truly random?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276206/) shows how to circumvent this problem – by generating ordered tuples of different numbers in $[0,104]$ instead of $[0,100]$, and subtracting $1$ from the differences.